# Hiding or Showing Google Ad View in Swift with Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, adsense

In my game I would like there to be an Google Banner View in the main menu scene and game over scene. Here's what I have in the GameViewController:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews(){
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    let skView = self.view as! SKView

    googleBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)

    googleBannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"

    googleBannerView.rootViewController = self

    var request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
    googleBannerView.loadRequest(request)

    googleBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, skView.bounds.height - googleBannerView.frame.size.height, googleBannerView.frame.size.width, googleBannerView.frame.size.height)

    self.view.addSubview(googleBannerView!)

    if skView.scene == nil{

        let mainMenuScene = MainMenuScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        mainMenuScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
        mainMenuScene.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        skView.presentScene(mainMenuScene)
    }
}

func showBanner(){
    if googleBannerView != nil{
        self.googleBannerView!.hidden = false
        var request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
        self.googleBannerView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}

func hideBanner(){
    println("hideBanner() called")
    self.googleBannerView.hidden = true
}
```

In the GameScene I have this:

```
 override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)

    let gameViewController = GameViewController()

    gameViewController.hideBanner()
```

When I run this it starts up fine, but when I press play it crashes and says: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. This doesn't make much sense because it can't be nil because I know there is an ad banner, right? What I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

-Vinny

Answer (score 0):

There could possibly be an error in your show banner function. Try taking out the exclamation in:

```
   self.googleBannerView!.hidden = false
```

If the banner view is not nil, then it doesn't need to unwrapped

Comment: Hi. Thank you for responding. Unfortunately your suggestion did not work. The problem is with the hideBanner() function. Any ideas?

Comment: Im a beginner myself so my answer wasn't of much help but when it comes to this error,  a good way to find errors when using optionals is using if statements to make sure your optional has some value or outputting optional values before using them to make sure they have some value inside them

Comment: Thank you for responding. It turns out that for some reason the ad banner is always equal to nil. I have know idea why, do you? Thank you in advance.